# List of Counts in the Correct Order

Tags: python, list, count, compression

For the list:

```
names=['fred', 'fred', 'fred', 'bill', 'bill', 'ted', 'ted', 'ted', 'ted']
```

I would like to return a list of counts for each name:

```
desired_list=[3,2,4]
```

Note the count of each name is in the same order as in the list 'names'.

Code I have tried:
Input:

```
name_count=[names.count(x) for x in set(names)]
```

Output:

```
[4, 3, 2]
```

......but it is in the wrong order. It should be [3,2,4]...the same order as the names in the names list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)

```
from collections import Counter

names = ['fred', 'fred', 'fred', 'bill', 'bill', 'ted', 'ted', 'ted', 'ted']

print(list(Counter(names).values()))
```

---

```
[3, 2, 4]
```

Comment: Great thankyou......how do you then get rid of 'dict_values'.......so it just reads: [3,2,4]

Answer (score 0):

Another option using `groupby` from `itertools` and list comprehension is:

```
from itertools import groupby
names=['fred', 'fred', 'fred', 'bill', 'bill', 'ted', 'ted', 'ted', 'ted']

res = [len(list(g[1])) for g in groupby(names)]
print(res)
```

Which returns:

```
[3, 2, 4]
```